# Calculating frequency from a blinking LED

Tags: led, frequency

Using a CD4027 and CD4060, I've connected the Q14 pin on the 4060 to the clock input of the 4027 and want to measure the Q output on the 4027 using an LED light.

The time interval is 100 seconds and the number of times the LED blinks in this period is 101.  How do I calculate the frequency with this information?

[image]

Comment: You could draw a schematic with the tool if you edit your question

Comment: How did you perform the timing? Did the 100 second interval start with the first LED blink?

Answer (score 2):

From your schematic the blink rate should be 1.0 Hz. Pin 3 of the 4060 is the divide by 2^14 output and the JK flipflop adds another divisor of 2. Therefore the 32.768 KHz clock is divided down by 2^15 giving a 1 blink per second.

You probably started the 100 second timing period when the LED blinked. Therefore the 101 blinks includes the blink that started the timing.

The frequency is the number of blink periods in the timing interval. Even though there are 101 blinks the number of periods (times between blinks) is only 100. Therefore the frequency is 100 periods/100 seconds = 1.0 Hz.

Answer (score 1):

Frequency is defined as cycles per second. Based on your information, your signal has  101 cycles in 100 seconds. Therefore the frequency is 101/100 = 1.01 Hertz. Note that a Hertz is the unit for cycles/second.

Comment: The answer could be 1.0 Hz if the timing started with the first blink. Indeed, the schematic suggests a 1 Hz blink rate.